# Split string with two delimiters into grouped arrays (explode twice)

Tags: php, split

```
$string = "1-2-3-4 5-6-7-8";
```

'-' = Separates Values

' ' = New array

```
$array1 = explode("-", $string, 4);
```

I have this code so far which will do values 1 to 4 but I want it to stop at 4 and create a new set.

Ex.

---

```
$SET_1[0] = 1
$SET_1[1] = 2
$SET_1[2] = 3
$SET_1[3] = 4
```

Then

```
$SET_2[0] = 5
$SET_2[1] = 6
$SET_2[2] = 7
$SET_2[3] = 8
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, also how would I reverse this after I have put them into arrays?

Comment: *how would I reverse this* - Reverse what? The order of the chunks? The elements in each chunk? Both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
$string = "1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8";
$data = array_chunk(explode('-', $string), 4);
```

which will return

```
$data = array(
   array('1', '2', '3', '4'),
   array('4', '5', '6', '7')
);
```

** **UPDATE** **

This will create an array of arrays containing each at most 4 elements. If you need variable size arrays, specified by `' '` in your string, use this instead :

```
$string2 = "1-2-3-4 5-6-7-8-9-10";

function inner_split(&$items) {
    $items = explode('-', $items);
}
$data2 = explode(' ', $string2);
array_walk($data2, 'inner_split');

var_dump($data2);
```

which will output

```
$data2 = array(
   array('1', '2', '3', '4'),
   array('5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10')
);
```

Comment: It's missing an 8 though because of the space, should I just be containing the data like so:
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8?

Comment: @tjmoore1993 Yes. With that method, you have to store them with dashes as delimeter throughout.

Comment: if you want even sized chunks, yes. I'll update the answer if you need variable sized array splits using the space

Comment: Not a problem, it beats storing the values in separate columns in database. :) Thanks again!

This answer is perfect, it actually was not what I was aiming for in a reply but it was exactly what I wanted! :)

Answer (score 0):

First split with whitespace into chunks of number sets, then split the numbers with "-" into arrays. You'll need to split the whitespace using Regex.

You should use `preg_split(regex, string)` and the whitespace character is \s in Regex. So something like `preg_split('/\s/', $string)`.

Answer (score 0):

what you want are multidimensional arrays:

so something like

```
 $set[i] = explode('-',$string, 4)
```

then just nest this in a loop and iterate over the string, you'll be able to access each individual character as

```
 $set[i][j]
```

where i is the set index and j is 1,2,3 or 4